# Gulp with templating, PHP framework or anything else for front-end developer

Tags: php, angular, frontend, backend, backendless

I am a front-end developer and I have a project where I need to build 3-5 pages website. The main work is in javascript communicating with REST API but I do want to have partials, routing if possible and templating.

Right now, I am literally frustrated with amount of available frameworks but I really would prefer not to setup PHP backend as it is not required (Wordpress either).

I feel very comfortable with the following technologies and frameworks being able to build entire front-end:

- Gulp
- Bootstrap
- JavaScript
- HTML/CSS/SASS

So I started to look into Angular but it feels like an overkill and with possible SEO issues even if it is 3 pages website for now.

Then, I started to look into static generators such as Jekyll but I would never develop in Ruby or Go.

Then I started to look into JavaScript templating + Gulp such as Mustache or Nunjucks and that sounds interesting although no routing would be possible.

Now I started to think if I shell create a simple PHP routing + template class in the website folder without MVC and the rest just do through Gulp as I am used to.

From what I've seen, people recommend going with PHP framework such as Symfony or Slim but I am not a back-end developer and afraid this can take much time from developing front part.

I would appreciate any opinion about this and I apologise if for someone that does not make sense but I do feel frustrated and decided to ask the community and experts that being in similar situations.

Thank you!

Comment: Way too open question to answer. Simplest way: take JS/jQuery and to requests to PHP backend. No framework

Comment: You mentioned backendless in the tags, this actually may be useful for your purposes: https://backendless.com. No need to set up any backend servers, lots of APIs available out of the box. Also there are automatically generated templates for your frontend with a number of frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Stack Overflow question, as you ask for an opinion, but I am willing to answer you anyway.

Setting up a Jekyll website does not require you to write any Ruby. Jekyll is simple, but does have partials, templating and routing. Therefore it seems like a good choice. I would use vanilla JavaScript or jQuery for the API interaction.

I use Jekyll for all websites that are smaller than 100 pages.